# How to integrate existing gstreamer video stream with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, pygst

Hi i'm  using gstreamer for multimedia streaming from raspberry pi to remote PC.
Im using these piplelines  in my raspberry pi

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-    1.0 -v fdsrc ! 
h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=YOUR_RPI_IP_ADDRESS port=5000.
```

On my PC i'm using this command to view stream

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=YOUR_RPI_IP_ADDRESS  port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  
rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink  
sync=false
```

now i would like to  view the stream on PC with a python code.I started looking into pygst,but couldn't figure out how to achieve this.Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

For python3/Gst1.*/Gtk3 pygst is basically deprecated. You should move to the [GObject introspection API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/). You can find [a lot of examples](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python%20gstreamer%20gobject) like [this one](http://brettviren.github.io/pygst-tutorial-org/pygst-tutorial.pdf).

The simplest example I can come up with of a working gstreamer pipeline in python is

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, Gtk

Gst.init(None)


pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=file:///path/to/my/video.ext')

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

Gtk.main()
```

You can use Gst.parse_launch to specify a pipeline declaratively like you would do with gst-launch. If you need more control on the pipeline creation/functionality you should create that programmatically. In this case you should read the GStreamer doc for more information and examples.

You would probably like to embed your video output inside some window, usually a GTK one, like in [this tutorial](https://blogs.gnome.org/uraeus/2011/10/04/tutorial-for-python-gstreamer-and-gtk-3/)